# $_POST on localserver (openserver) doesn't work

Tags: php, post, localhost

I working with Retrofit2, Volley(android libraries) and tried to make **$_POST** request on server. Firstly i thought some errors in my android application code, but when i tested it on Postman, i realised that error is on server. I don't have any idea what problem is it, but when i using **$_GET** request it works fine. The problem is only on local server, because when i worked on some paid hosting i didn't saw any of those problems.

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

This row displays empty array.

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: @alynurly All code that i have in my php script row that in my post.